# Android ListView StateListDrawable between Choice Mode Multi Modal & Choice Mode Single

Tags: android, android-listview, android-drawable, statelistdrawable

I have a very simple listview in my app. I allow users to tap on any item on the listview upon which a new activity is called to show additional information of that item. This happens in the choice mode single. I also allow users to long press on any item upon which I present a context menu. One of the options in that context menu is Multi Select. It enables users to select multiple items and delete them in single shot. In this case I switch to CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL.

To change the background of the selected items, I am using background drawable in the listview item layout xml which points to a selector. Something like below:

List Item Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/multi_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/foo_bar">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/foo_bar_desc" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Drawable multi_background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/DarkBlue"></item>
</selector>
```

This works fine and gives the desired result when selecting multiple items in the multi choice mode. However, once after I invoke the multi select option on the listview even if I tap on the list item to view additional information, the background changes to blue for just about a second before switching to the activity to show additional information. However, if I tap on the list item just after entering the app without going into the multi select option the behavior is just fine. The background of the tapped item is changed to the default dark grey of the Holo theme and the activity to show additional information starts without that one second delay.

Am I not doing something I should be doing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you show us your entire xml?

Comment: @RodrigoHenriques, Sure. It is quite simple. I have updated it now.

Comment: have you tried to define the other color states on your states list selector?

Comment: No, I didn't define anything else. Because, this is the only thing I need different from the default behavior. What do you think I should add there.

Comment: Have you tried to rollback your list choice mode after this multi selection?

Comment: It looks like if your list is multi choice any click will cause the activated state, so it causes the dark blue effect in your item after your click.

Comment: Yes. I roll back the choice mode to single after the business with multi choice is done

Comment: thats an strange behavior

Comment: Yes, it is strange. Indeed.